# What are ways to detect running under windows 10 emulation?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, emulation

Since a binary built for Ubuntu may now run under the Win10 "Ubuntu subsystem" -  how can it detect this? (besides of poking in obscure corners of sysfs, /dev and so on)

Comment: What's wrong with poking obscure corners? That's likely where the answer lies.

Comment: does `/etc/lsb-release` show a string for Windows?

Comment: @Rinzwind Nope, there is no information about Windows at all.  See "What can I do with WSL?" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq.

Answer (score 3):

The [WSL faq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq) does not show anything about identifying bash on windows.

Notable though:  Bash for Windows will have a mount point for the Windows devices. So when a ...

```
/mnt/c:
```

exists you are using bash on Windows (remark: that FAQ from Microsoft is probably wrong and it is [/mnt/c](http://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/) and not `/mnt/c:`. Same applies for D: and other drive letters (that are disks).

Comment: In fact, it is `/mnt/c`, not `/mnt/c:`. My Windows home for example is on `/mnt/c/Users/Philipp`.

Comment: @kleinfreund well it used to be c: according to microsoft themself. Plus I already have it in the answer: "remark: that FAQ from Microsoft is probably wrong and it is /mnt/c"

Answer (score 2):

This looks like one of possibilities:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease
```

Under WSL it contains "Microsoft".